# KQL: aggregate row by time shift and get value of the more recent row

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I think it's more easy to look at the data.
We've an application that tracks all user interaction inside an intranet.

| eventType | pageUrl | timestamp | timeOnPageMs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pageEvent | https://url1.com/ | 2021-11-05T06:10:11.591Z | 0 |
| pageEvent | https://url1.com/ | 2021-11-05T06:20:11.591Z | 23123 |
| pageEvent | https://url2.com/ | 2021-11-05T06:11:11.591Z | 0 |
| pageEvent | https://url2.com/ | 2021-11-05T06:30:11.591Z | 23123 |

**Open page event** are identified having `timeOnPageMs=0`, otherwise it's **close page** event.

I want to define a query that extracts all page open events, but with timeOnPageMs of the page close event.

| eventType | pageUrl | timestamp | timeOnPageMs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| pageEvent | https://url1.com/ | 2021-11-05T06:10:11.591Z | 23123 |
| pageEvent | https://url2.com/ | 2021-11-05T06:11:11.591Z | 33123 |

I tried using a UDF that lookups the required value, but it seems not possible as described in last reply [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-monitor/inject-column-as-parameter-in-a-defined-function-inside-a-join/m-p/1373126).

Thanks in advance for anyone who'll help!

Giacomo S.S.

Comment: How do you want to correlate events, if there are multiple Open events of the same URL, followed by multiple Close events of the same URL? Do you have a SessionID, or something?

Comment: @SlavikN, thanks a lot for editing the question! Yes, in reality we've both an AAD identifier of the user and a session ID too. Inside this _frame_, I'd like to correlate a given **open event** of an URL with the close event of the first same URL **close event** with greater timestamp. For the moment I solved bringing a new _dataset_ inside PowerBI.

Comment: Great. Since you have a sessionId, the solution is very simple. Please see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a SessionId to correlate events (to be able to handle cases when there are multiple Open events of the same URL, followed by multiple Close events of the same URL).

And then this is how you solve it:

```
datatable(eventType:string, pageUrl:string, timestamp:datetime, timeOnPageMs:long, sessionId:string)
[
    "pageEvent","https://url1.com/",datetime(2021-11-05T06:10:11.591Z),0,"id1",
    "pageEvent","https://url1.com/",datetime(2021-11-05T06:10:15.591Z),0,"id2",
    "pageEvent","https://url1.com/",datetime(2021-11-05T06:11:12.591Z),1500,"id2",
    "pageEvent","https://url1.com/",datetime(2021-11-05T06:20:11.591Z),23123,"id1",
    "pageEvent","https://url2.com/",datetime(2021-11-05T06:11:11.591Z),0,"id3",
    "pageEvent","https://url2.com/",datetime(2021-11-05T06:30:11.591Z),23123,"id3"
]
| summarize take_any(eventType, pageUrl), min(timestamp), max(timeOnPageMs) by sessionId
```

Result:

| sessionId | eventType | pageUrl | min_timestamp | max_timeOnPageMs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 | pageEvent | https://url1.com/ | 2021-11-05 06:10:11.5910000 | 23123 |
| id2 | pageEvent | https://url1.com/ | 2021-11-05 06:10:15.5910000 | 1500 |
| id3 | pageEvent | https://url2.com/ | 2021-11-05 06:11:11.5910000 | 23123 |